# print pdf in popup and get error "Member Not Found"

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, pdf

I use to print pdf in popup and get error "Member Not Found".

```
<script > 
var url;
url = 'test.aspx?SID=" + ID + "&Val=" + 2 + "&Loc=" + US + "';
var SaveCaseBrowser; 
SaveCaseBrowser=window.open(url ,'Rpt','width=800,height=600,toolbar=yes,status=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,menubar=yes,location=no');
if((SaveCaseBrowser == null)||(typeof(SaveCaseBrowser)== 'undefined'))
{alert('An error occurred trying to launch a new window.');
}
else
{ 
try
{ 
setTimeout(function () { SaveCaseBrowser.focus(); }, 100); } catch(e) { SaveCaseBrowser.Close(); SaveCaseBrowser=window.open(url ,'Rpt','width=800,height=600,toolbar=yes,status=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,menubar=yes,location=no'); }}</script>")
```

c# code is:

```
string saveCaseScript = string.Empty;
    saveCaseScript = (Above Script are here);
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "rpt", saveCaseScript);
```

thanks

Comment: As this is javascript - I'm confused how you can get a `permission denied` error in asp.net.

Comment: @mrtsherman He is opening a popup window with a ASP.NET page..

Comment: Its an Javascript error. same code works fine for not pdf output but in the case of PDF its shows error.

Comment: He needs to post his server side code then. This has nothing to do with javascript.

Comment: @Sam - try opening the URL by copying and pasting it into a browser. I bet it doesn't work. If your server is displaying 'Permission Denied' in the retrieved page it has nothing to do with js and everything to do with your server.

Comment: Yes let me clear, its shows error msg on parent page refresh or any postback (change of values) on that. when I use debugger it stop at SaveCaseBrowser.focus().

Comment: Any One Have the relevent...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I close the popup window befor open new one. I use this scenario untill the next solution i find.
hope may be you have the same problem.

```
var CD; //Open Report. 
    function openNewWin(url) {
      try {
        CD = window.open(url, "Popup", 'width=800,height=600,toolbar=yes,status=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,menubar=yes,location=no');
        CD.focus();
      }
      catch (e) {
        CD.close();
        CD = window.open(url, "Popup", 'width=800,height=600,toolbar=yes,status=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,menubar=yes,location=no');
        CD.focus();
      }
    }
```